# regex to match variable declaration in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to parse a variable declaration statement and get the variable name. I am doing the below

```
String var = "private   String   ipaddress;";
```

i m using the regex pattern below to match the above string

```
.*private\\s+([a-z]*)\\s+([a-z0-9_]*);
```

It does not work. It says no match found Can any one please help.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - although that might enable us to help you even better: what's the use case for this? What do you want to achieve with that parsing?

Answer (score 10):

First of all, remove that dot from the beginning of the regex, since it requires a character before the `private` for a match.

Second, your regex is case sensitive and won't match the capital s. Either use `[a-zA-Z]` or make the expression case insensitive (`(?i)` at the start IIRC).

Btw, `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` would be the same as `\w`.

Another thing: your expression would also catch illegal variable names as well as miss legal ones. Variables are not allowed to start with a number but they could also contain dollar signs. Thus the name expression should be something like `([a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*)` meaning the first character must be a letter, underscore or dollar sign followed by any number of word characters or dollar signs.

A last note: depending on what you do with those declarations, keep in mind that you might have to check for those reserved words. The adjusted expression would still match `"private String private"`, for example.

Another last note: keep in mind that there might more modifiers than `private` for a variable, e.g. `public`, `protected`, `static` etc. - or none at all.

*Edit*:

Now that you have the asterisk after the first dot, that shouldn't be a problem for your special case. However, a dot matches almost any character and thus would match `fooprivate` as well. Depending on what you want to achieve either remove the dot or add a `\s+` after the `.*`.

Comment: the dot at the beginning is correct, since it is followed by an `*` which will also matches no occurrence of the dot.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger yes, now it is somewhat correct, although it would match `barprivate` as well. However, when I wrote that, the asterisk was missing (or at least I didn't see it due to formatting issues) :)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger that's true, especially if he eventually wants to parse complete source files (I don't still know what he's trying to achieve).

Answer (score 5):

Since the declaration of a variable in Java can have more the 3 words before the variable name, I would suggest you do not limit your search and use this:

```
String var = "private   String   ipaddress;";
//String var2 = "private static final int test=13;";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+\\s(.+?)(;|=)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(var);

while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

It will look for any variable name that begins with a whitespace and ends with either ";" or "=". This is a more general search of variable name.

**EDIT** This one got me thinking actually, since this is also legal declaration in Java:

```
private
static
volatile
String
s , t1 = "";
```

This actually could be improved probably as it was thinked/done fast.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String var0 = "private static final int test,test2;";
String var1 = "private \n static \n final \n int \n testName \n =\n   5 \n";
String var2 = "private \n static \n final \n String \n testName \n =\n  \" aaa           = bbbb   \" \n";
String var3 = "private \n static \n final \n String \n testName,testName2 \n =\n  \" aaa           = bbbb   \" \n";

String var4 = "int i;";
String var5 = "String s ;";
String var6 = "final String test ;  ";
String var7 = "public int go = 23;";
String var8 = "public static final int value,valu2 ; ";
String var9 = "public static final String t,t1,t2 = \"23\";";
String var10 = "public \n static \n final \n String s1,s2,s3 = \" aaa , bbb, fff, = hhh = , kkk \";";
String var11 = "String myString=\"25\"";

LinkedList<String> input = new LinkedList<String>();
input.add(var0);input.add(var1);input.add(var2);input.add(var3);input.add(var4);input.add(var5);
input.add(var6);input.add(var7);input.add(var8);input.add(var9);input.add(var10);
input.add(var11);

LinkedList<String> result = parametersNames(input);
for(String param: result){
    System.out.println(param);
}

}

private static LinkedList<String> parametersNames(LinkedList<String> input){
LinkedList<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
for(String var: input){

    if(var.contains("\n")) var = var.replaceAll("\n", "");
    var = var.trim();
    if(var.contains("=")){
        var = var.substring(0, var.indexOf("=")).trim() + "";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+\\s(.+)$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(var);

       if(m.find()){
        if(m.group(1).contains(",")){
            String [] tokens = m.group(1).split(",");
            for(String token : tokens){
            result.add(token);
            }
        } else{
            result.add(m.group(1));
        }
        }

    } else{
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+\\s(.+?)(;|=)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(var);

        if(m.find()){
        if(m.group(1).contains(",")){
            String [] tokens = m.group(1).split(",");
            for(String token : tokens){
            result.add(token);
            }
        } else{
            result.add(m.group(1));
        }
        }
    }
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: Zoiks.  Why not use `/gm` to match multiline and avoid the complexity?  Also, the use case is going to be looking at a file/stream not single lines/strings.

Comment: @ShaneK because almost 10 years ago I was a very different person and developer :)

Answer (score 3):

`.*private\\s+(\\w*)\\s+(\\w*);`
use this pattern. [a-z] is a lowercase letter, but "String" in your text starts with uppercase `S`. `\\w` is a word character. It's the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
It seems that your texts will be like `"private <type> <field name>;"` and if it's so, your type can contain uppercase lowercase letters, numbers or underlines, so writing `\\w` is a good solution.

Comment: slight correction: the second z in your definition of `\w` should be upper case :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use this regex:

```
^(?s)\\s*private\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s*;\\s*$
```

This will make sure to match:

- Case insensitive match except keyword `private`
- Multi line declarations
- white spaces at start, end and in the middle

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Checkstyle regex patterns for naming conventions (types, methods, packages etc). More info [here](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html).