# Regex to match variable declaration

Tags: java, regex

I need to match something like this:

```
int a= 4, b, c = "hi";
```

I already made a regex that successfully strips everything away from the line, leaving only

```
a= 4, b, c = "hi"
```

I don't care about the types of the variables, like "hi" being a `String`, because that will be checked later in the code.

Basically, I need to match a variable declaration with everything stripped off except the variables themselves, with or without the = part.

These are examples that should not match:

```
a b= 4
var,
,hello=3
=8
```

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189393/regex-to-match-variable-declaration-in-java) question out, it didn't really help.

I have tried [this](https://regex101.com/r/rE5nF0/2) code, but there are a couple of problems, namely pretty much everything that I have listed in the things that shouldn't match, do match.

Also there might be more things that I missed.
I am supposed to match strings with spaces, for example `a = "hello there"`, and there isn't a requirement to match a string with `,` inside it.

"Formal" defenition of what a variable name can be:

Variable name can be any sequence (length > 0) of letters (uppercase or lowercase), digits and the underscore character. Name may not start with a digit. Name may start with an underscore, but in such a case it must contain at least one more character

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not quite clear, pleas specify exactly what output you expect for a given input. I have tried to come up with something, but I am not sure what you need. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rE5nF0/3).

Answer (score 2):

## Description

Taking from your regex101 example, I'm not exactly clear on the other requirements so I realize this may not completely answer your question.

```
"[^"]*"|((?=_[a-z_0-9]|[a-z])[a-z_0-9]+(?=\s*=))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- matches quoted strings
- places the variable names into Capture Group 1, you can then iterate through the array of matches testing the capture group 1 for a value, if it's populated then it's a name.
- requires variable name to start with either `_` and at least one character, or start with an a-z
- after the first letter the variable names can contain any number of `a-z` `_` or `0-9`
- variables names must be followed by an `=` sign
- any number of spaces can be around the `=` sign

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/aT6sC4/1

**Sample text**

```
name = "steve", bro = "4, hi = bye", lolwot = "wait wot"
```

**Sample Matches**

Note how capture group 1 only contains the variable names.

```
[0][0] = name
[0][1] = name

[1][0] = "steve"
[1][1] = 

[2][0] = bro
[2][1] = bro

[3][0] = "4, hi = bye"
[3][1] = 

[4][0] = lolwot
[4][1] = lolwot

[5][0] = "wait wot"
[5][1] =
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      _                        '_'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-z_0-9]                any character of: 'a' to 'z', '_', '0'
                               to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z_0-9]+               any character of: 'a' to 'z', '_', '0'
                             to '9' (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                               (0 or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I would like it to capture both the variable name and the variable value, like in the demo that I provided. I don't quite understand how your example works so I don't know where to put a second capturing group. Also, I need to match something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/qD8wF5/1) to extract the value of 4... Thanks for helping <3

Comment: [This demo](https://regex101.com/r/eJ3bK3/1) captures both the variable name and it's assigned value.

Comment: I would change your regex myself if I understood it, but I notice the following problems: 1) It matches `hi =`, and 2) it doesn't match `var1= var2` (just to be clear, I also need to match variable = variable, not only strings or numbers, and 3) it doesn't match `num = 5.0`. Thanks a lot for your help, I would never achieve that myself

Comment: Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/aT6sC4/2 I can't get this to match the floating b in the substring `a=1, b, c=2`  because then it would also match the `clear,` that appears later in your text. Also this will match any commented out values too. The expression is multiline to improve readability but can be condensed to a single line.

Comment: I don't really care if it matches arbitary text since I check the things around it, so it doesn't matter if it matches `clear,` for example. But I do care a lot about it matching the `b` in the text, so that's much preferred if it did match `b` and `clear,` as a side effect. Also, it might be a too complicated task for regex... So maybe it will need breaking into a couple smaller regexes...

Comment: Ok, have a look at this https://regex101.com/r/aT6sC4/3 which will of course matches the `b,` but also several other variable names followed by a comma. Note that the comma can be preceded by zero or more spaces.

Comment: Also had someone from an IRC help me, here is what he did: https://regex101.com/r/aT6sC4/7